# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

The solution to this problem is not sending keys
I want a solution,
This is the website link: https://mahmoud-magdy.com/register

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://mahmoud-magdy.com/register')
driver.find_element_by_id('first_name').send_keys(monster)
driver.find_element_by_id('last_name').send_keys(monster)
driver.find_element_by_name('phone').send_keys(phone)
driver.find_element_by_name('father_phone').send_keys(father_phone)
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name('password_confirmation').send_keys(password_confirmation)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type="submit"]').click()
print(phone)
driver.quit()
```

When I try to send keys to first name this problem appears

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your question, so that we can better understand what the problem is.

Comment: do you not understand the error message? What is your question or what are you expecting from us?

Comment: chanage `driver.find_element_by_name` to `driver.find_element` [check this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 2):

`find_element_by_*` methods no more supported by Selenium from Selenium 4.3 version.
You need to use a new syntax.
In your case it should be as following:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://mahmoud-magdy.com/register')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'first_name').send_keys(monster)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'last_name').send_keys(monster)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'phone').send_keys(phone)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'father_phone').send_keys(father_phone)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email').send_keys(email)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password_confirmation').send_keys(password_confirmation)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type="submit"]').click()
print(phone)
driver.quit()
```

You will need this import for that:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```